# Converting string to long

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to convert a string to long. It sounds easy, but I still get the same error. I tried:

```
include <iostream>
include <string>    

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string myString = "";
  cin >> myString;
  long myLong = atol(myString);
}
```

But always the error:

```
.../main.cpp:12: error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'long int atol(const char*)'
```

occured.
The reference says following:

```
long int atol ( const char * str );
```

Any help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
long myLong = std::stol( myString );
```

The function has three parameters

```
long stol(const string& str, size_t *idx = 0, int base = 10);
```

You can use the second parameter that to determine the position in the string where parsing of the number was stoped. For example

```
std::string s( "123a" );

size_t n;

std::stol( s, &n );

std::cout << n << std::endl;
```

The output is

```
3
```

The function can throw exceptions.

Answer (score 8):

Just write

```cpp
long myLong = atol(myString.c_str());
```

Comment: is this c 11 standard?

Answer (score 3):

`atol()` requires a **`const char*`**; there's no *implicit* conversion from `std::string` to `const char*`, so if you really want to use `atol()`, you must call the **`std::string::c_str()`** method to get the raw C-like string pointer to be passed to `atol()`:

```
// myString is a std::string
long myLong = atol(myString.c_str());
```

A better C++ approach would be using [**`stol()`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stol/) (available since C++11), without relying on a C function like `atol()`:

```
long myLong = std::stol(myString);
```

Answer (score 1):

`atol` gets as parameter a `const char*` (C-style string), but you are passing as parameter a `std::string`. The compiler is not able to find any viable conversion between `const char*` and `std::string`, so it gives you the error. You can use the `string` member function `std::string::c_str()`, which returns a c-style string, equivalent to the contents of you `std::string`. Usage:

```
string str = "314159265";
cout << "C-ctyle string: " << str.c_str() << endl;
cout << "Converted to long: " << atol(str.c_str()) << endl;
```